# Using strncat with char array element in C

Tags: c, string, char, character

I have get error with the following code and i can't figure it out.

```
   char name[]="tolgahan"
   char result[100]="";
   strncat(result,name[1],1);
```

I guess, i need to convert name[1] to string format but i don't now how can i do that.

Please help me.
Best regards.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It seems like you are trying to copy the second letter of the name into the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
strncat(result, & name[1],1);
```

or

```
strncat(result, name + 1,1);
```

Explanation: A string in C is just the address (in memory) of the first character in a sequence of characters. So if you take the pointer (using the & operator or by adding 1 to the initial pointer), you get a string starting at the 2nd character of the initial string.

Comment: Warning: Note that the above won't work properly if strncat actually has to truncate a string that is too long. stncpy and strncat *stupidly* (IMHO) will not NUL terminate your string in this case. You should always follow a strncpy() or strncat() with (in this example) result[99] = '\0'; to be sure that the resulting string is NUL terminated, or you may end up with a nasty crash. (I say 'stupidly' because a NUL terminated string without a NUL terminator is plain broken, and 'str...' functions are supposed to work with NUL terminated strings, ergo, they should not produce broken strings!)

Comment: @Jason Williams: `strncat` *always* NUL terminates. `strncpy` makes no such guarantee.

Comment: @jamesdlin: ok, fair enough. 'Tis just strncpy that is wildly inconsitent and irritating then :-) (I checked to be sure, but managed to find a rather poor reference page :-)

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
name[1]
```

is a character - you want a pointer:

```
strncat(result,name + 1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

But using `strncat` for a 1 character copy is overkill and not really smart.

in your case I would do something more like this

```
 char name[]="tolgahan";
 char result[100]= "";
 size_t l = 0;
 result[l++] = name[1];
```

By tracking the length of my first string I can avoid hidden `strlen` calls (that's what `strncat` does internally).

```
 result[l++] = 'H';
 result[l++] = 'e';
 result[l++] = 'l';
 result[l++] = 'l';
 result[l++] = 'o';
 result[l++] = 0;
```

I still have the real length of my string in `l` and I avoided a call and the compiler can even rearrange things internally to use fewer memory operations.